# ASP.NET Core Angular Template - Component styles do not get applied after ng build --prod

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new ASP.NET Core Angular application with .NET Core SDK 3.1 (Visual Studio 2019)
2. Add a new CSS file (home.component.css) to the home component
3. Update home.component.ts to include the newly added CSS file

```css
.acs-h1 {
  color: blueviolet
}
```

```html
<h1 class="acs-h1">Hello, world!</h1>
<p>Welcome to your new single-page application, built with:</p>
<ul>
  <li><a href='https://get.asp.net/'>ASP.NET Core</a> and <a href='https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx'>C#</a> for cross-platform server-side code</li>
  <li><a href='https://angular.io/'>Angular</a> and <a href='http://www.typescriptlang.org/'>TypeScript</a> for client-side code</li>
  <li><a href='http://getbootstrap.com/'>Bootstrap</a> for layout and styling</li>
</ul>
<p>To help you get started, we've also set up:</p>
<ul>
  <li><strong>Client-side navigation</strong>. For example, click <em>Counter</em> then <em>Back</em> to return here.</li>
  <li><strong>Angular CLI integration</strong>. In development mode, there's no need to run <code>ng serve</code>. It runs in the background automatically, so your client-side resources are dynamically built on demand and the page refreshes when you modify
    any file.</li>
  <li><strong>Efficient production builds</strong>. In production mode, development-time features are disabled, and your <code>dotnet publish</code> configuration automatically invokes <code>ng build</code> to produce minified, ahead-of-time compiled JavaScript
    files.</li>
</ul>
<p>The <code>ClientApp</code> subdirectory is a standard Angular CLI application. If yo**strong text**u open a command prompt in that directory, you can run any <code>ng</code> command (e.g., <code>ng test</code>), or use <code>npm</code> to install extra packages into
  it.</p>
```

4. Run the application locally, style from home.component.css gets applied
5. Publish and deploy the application, style from home.component.css does not apply and additionally none of the default styles from the nav-menu.component.css gets applied in the deployed package

I have tried the same with .NET Core SDK 3.0 and got the same result.

Also noticed that the default ASP.NET Core Angular template has a `<body>` tag in the index.html as well as in the app.component.html. I tried removing the one from app.component.html but it did not helped.

Comment: How do you publish?I publish a new 3.1 angular core project to my IIS without any problem with the style.

Comment: I just right click on the web project and publish to a local folder and then copy the files to the IIS folder

Comment: Do you have nodejs installed on your server? I do not have nodejs installed on my IIS server. Could that be the issue?

Comment: nodejs has no effect on a published project.I follow this tutorial:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#create-the-iis-site

Comment: I follow the same. The reason I asked about nodejs because when I deploy the same package on my development machine IIS (Windows 10) the style works but the same package when deployed on Windows Server IIS the style does not work. I am wondering if there is any dependency that is missing on the Windows Server which is causing the issue.